# Is the argument to Promise.prototype.then's callback always the result internal property of the Promise object .then is on?

Tags: javascript

Can I confirm that the argument to `.then`'s (first or second) callback will always be the result internal property of the `Promise` object `.then` is on? In this example, I believe `5` to be the result internal property of Promise object `promise`.

```js
let promise = new Promise (function(resolve, reject) {
resolve(5)
})

promise.then(value => console.log(value))
```

---

*Snippet for additional question*

```js
console.log(
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve(5);
}).then(value => 6)
)
```

Comment: Yes, why would you expect something else?

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, just wanted to make sure as the article I'm reading doesn't explicitly say it. Whilst I have you here would it be possible to also confirm `.then` returns a new Promise object whose result internal property is the same value as what the `.then`'s executor function returns? (I've added an additional snippet to the question that I think is an example of that statement)

Comment: No, a `.then` has no "executor function". And if you mean the callback, first of all there are two of them, and second they might return another promise not a plain value (or, third, even throw an exception), in which case the `.then(…)` promise will not have the callback's return value as its result.

Comment: @Bergi Yes I did mean callback. Okay, I can see that on the MDN documentation now. Thanks for clarifying this for me